# Entity Framework select from user specified table

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, entity-framework

I've looked around on this topic for a while now, but I couldn't find an answer that I actually understood (or someone asking about something close enough).

**Problem Description:**
I have a database with multiple tables, say `apples`, `oranges`, and `bananas`. That have a bunch of information under each. One of those properties is common, let's say `expirationDate`.

I need the user to be able to query the expiration date of one of those (for example, `apple` with `id=1`)

The user can choose all of this in a GUI (a combo box with the table names and a textbox for `id`)

**What I have so far:**
In the background code/business logic, I have the following

```
.
.
.
if(tableName.Equals("apples"))
  {
      DateTime expDate = getAppleDetails(id)
  }
if(tableName.Equals("oranges"))
  {
    //call function to select the single orangeEntry and do the rest
  }

}
DateTime getAppleDetails(long id)
{
   using(var db = new myContext())
   {
     var appleEntry = db.apples.Single(x=>x.id==id);
     return appleEntry.ExpDate
   }
}
```

**What I'm looking for:**
The above code shows you how with a larger sized database, I'll end having to duplicate A LOT of code. What's a better way of doing this in the same query?
Something like `db.TableNameHere.Single(x=> x.id == id)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an interface called for example `IExpirationDate` which looks like the following

```
public interface IExpirationDate
{
    DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
}
```

Your classes with `ExpirationDate` must implement `IExpirationDate`, for example

```
public class Orange : IExpirationDate
{
    //Other properties of the class

    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; } //Property from interface
}
```

When all the required classes implementing `IExpirationDate` interface you can have one generic method to get the expiration date for any of them, which will look like this

```
public static DateTime GetExpirationDate<T>(long id) 
        where T : class, IExpirationDate
{
    using(var db = new myContext())
    {
        var entry = db.Set<T>.Find(id);
        return entry.ExpirationDate;
    }
}
```

Now, to get the expiration date for the `Orange` class you can just call

```
var expirationDate = GetExpirationDate<Orange>(id);
```

Comment: Would that not still require me to specify the table in code? I mean that in a sense where I will have to go through and compare the string and call the function with the correct DBSet depending on what the string fetched from UI says?

It does significantly reduce the amount of duplicated code

Comment: Actually, I just tried implementing it and it does a good job of reducing the code for me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First of all a simple improvement is to use db.apples.Find(id) instead og db.Single(x=>x.id==id). Find is faster when you have the id.

You can use a generic Repository to mmake calls to the Database. 
This article http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle gives a fine explanation of the content.

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look at the blog post tonight and see how it can help me:)